# Bootstrap input-group-addon icons for non-inputs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

Bootstrap has a built-in icon for buttons: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

I was wondering if it was possible to keep this style of icon, but not for inputs? For example I want to have an icon appear as part of the panel title in the same style: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels, and possible also to be able the change the background color of the icon section?

What I need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkYYe.jpg

So I guess this is not a built in functionality. How would I about building a CSS for this myself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974864/add-button-addons-input-group-on-panel-heading Maybe this will help ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) section of the documentation. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/ntYx7/)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS to change the color.

```
.glyphicon {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm aware that I'm able to add icons to the panel title; I was particularly looking for something with the same style as their input-addon icon where there is a separator line between the icon and the title text. I was also hoping to be able to change the background color of the icon section of the title bar rather than the icon itself.
Please see the image I've attached.

Comment: Its not build-in functionality... you would have to create it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone searching for similar solutions.

I have found this bootstrap snippet that modifies the panel behavior to work horizontally:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panel-horizontal

[image: Horizontal panel]