# Add button addons/input_group on panel heading

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, panel

Regarding the input-groups-buttons bootstrap 3 feature :
https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

I would like to know how can I create a CSS that reproduced the same feature for panel-heading.

At this time, I have a button inside the panel heading (which I had to change a little CSS so it can fit in the panel-heading).

http://www.bootply.com/TjI7cyaYIu (without my little CSS hack)

So I want this button to be displayed the same way an input-group-button is.

A similar question may have been posted here : [Bootstrap input-group-addon icons for non-inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521488/bootstrap-input-group-addon-icons-for-non-inputs) but without any relevant answers.

I know this is not a bootstrap feature and my CSS skills are pretty low so I hope someone can help me !

Comment: [Here is a potencial answer](http://www.bootply.com/7hU1s76j7X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :) should work for u.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div style="width: 80%;"> Title goes Here </div>
      <div style="width: 20%;" class="text-right"> ICON </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/RR1vUVQh97

If you want to learn easily some CSS-Basics and how to use bootstrap, try codecademy ;)

------------------------------------------------------------------ EDIT:

Here is the solution including your button:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 80%">
      <h4 class="panel-title" style="margin-top: 7px;">MY TITLE</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%" class="text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nibh lorem, ultricies a luctus ac, congue et dui. Suspendisse a neque augue. Ut laoreet elit pretium dolor ullamcorper feugiat. Curabitur scelerisque, diam in tristique consequat, lacus quam sagittis lorem, ut gravida enim arcu ultricies mauris. Maecenas convallis pretium diam sed malesuada. Donec eget nunc id ligula elementum interdum vel vitae est. Morbi ut magna vulputate dui condimentum lobortis. Curabitur commodo eget lectus a mollis. Vestibulum eget fermentum enim, id commodo diam.
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/RltWAo76Bq

With edited border-radius: http://www.bootply.com/eYpYJz9BcW

Comment: I tried to modify your snippet and I can't manage to use `pull-right` class and add a `button` with an `<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>` in it ... nothing is displayed on the right side of the panel.

When I look at the available classes on bootply, I am pretty sure that all of them are not availables :( (But I can be wrong).

Comment: I know codecademy (I studied RoR on this site, it is pretty great). The problem is that I can not take the time to learn all CSS basics rith now (and I apologize for this). I know how to use bootstrap, but it seems that my request is not already implemented in it ... And I don't have the css skills to adapt the button.

Comment: My bad for the first answer with the fa class ... I had to had to font-awesome lib in order to make it available

Comment: I created a bootply with what I have for now on:

http://www.bootply.com/TjI7cyaYIu

Comment: That is what I have at this time (I have a -6px margin-top on the button).

The thing is that I would like the button to be appart from the panel (like an input-group-add-on).

If you take the bootstrap component : https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons. You can imagine that the input is the panel heading :) (I don't know if it is clear)

Comment: i dont really understand what you want :D somthing like this? http://www.bootply.com/qOMS8sGuRc

Comment: that's pretty much this but without the border radius on the left side of the button :)

Comment: Isn't it possible in the button style to refer to the .panel-heading height instead of fixing it in both of them ? (assuming that i'm NOT generating the button with jquery ... which, actually, i'm doing)

Comment: you hav to fix the height at both of them, because the panel-heading class normally brings a padding and a smaller height with it.
http://www.bootply.com/7hU1s76j7X

Comment: or look at this: now is the height of both more dynamic... with that solution you can use Titles wich goes on two or more lines, too. http://www.bootply.com/eYpYJz9BcW

Comment: OK, I validate this answer :)

Thanks a lot for your help and for taking the time to help me throught this !